# Is it safe to define a memory section over multiple physical memories?

Tags: microcontroller, memory

I am working on the memory mapping on my MCU.
Let's say I have this mapping for physical for memories:

```
 0x1000
     RAM 0
 0x2000
     RAM 1
 0x3000
```

Then I have memory allocation. In this part the RAM 1 is not used as a whole:

```
RAM0 : origin = 0x1000, length = 0x1000
RAM1 : origin = 0x2000, length = 0x400  // <= Only 1Ko used
```

Then I have sections:

```
.stack : > RAM0
.ebss  : > RAM1
```

This is just as an example, since it is not the reality of my project.

To avoid wasting memory in RAM 1, I'd like to create a memory allocation over both memories:

```
RAM0_M1PART1 : origin = 0x1000, length = 0x1C00  // <= Added 3Ko here
RAM1_PART2   : origin = 0x2C00, length = 0x400   // Moved at the end of the range (2C00 -> 3000)
```

**The question is *quite simple*: is it safe?**

Thank you!

Comment: what do you mean by *safe*? If the access to these memories is transparent for the MCU (i.e. no special initializations or access/mapping instructions involved), why would it matter?

Comment: I don't know exactly... What if an array or a structure is defined at the boundary of the memories for example?

Comment: Again, it depends on the architecture. If the MCU memory access instructions do not care about such a boundaries - you should not care as well. But of course there might be some restrictions that you should check.

Comment: What are you going to use the alternative memory segments (RAM0_M1PART1, and RAM1_PART2) for? Are you planning to ask the linker to place variables or code in all four memory segments within one program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the architecture of the the particular MCU, treating different blocks of physical memory as a contiguous area may or may not be safe. The blocks may be specified separately simply because that is how they are defined in the hardware, or they may be different types of memory that require different procedures to access (eg. Flash vs RAM, internal RAM vs external RAM) or have restricted access (eg. stack pointer can only address a small fixed area of the RAM, DMA controller is wired to a particular block).

The purpose of memory mapping is to tell the *compiler* how to use the memory. The compiler normally expects different sections to be separate from each other, whether in the same or different blocks of physical memory. If one section is mapped over another then it will try to use that same memory for different purposes, which could cause the program to fail (eg. stack running into bss and corrupting variables). This is obviously *not* safe!

The only time it is safe to map one section over another is if you intend the memory to be used for different purposes at different points in the program, and you *know* that the compiler won't get confused by this dual use.

So in your example where you want 3k more in the first section, first check that the hardware is capable of using the two RAM blocks contiguously for that purpose (eg. stack pointer not restricted to the first block). Then map the second section into the free area that is left, like this:-

```
RAM0_M1PART1 : origin = 0x1000, length = 0x1C00  // <= Added 3Ko here
RAM1_PART2   : origin = 0x2C00, length = 0x400
```

Comment: You are right, this is the mapping I had in mind... I realized that too and I changed it in my question! I really liked reading your first paragraph (I mean that one must be sure the memories are of the same type), so that is why I accepted your answer. Thank a lot!

Answer (score 3):

There are several interpretations of 'safe'.

One is, can the processor access RAM blocks as contiguous blocks?

That will be described in the datasheet for the part. I would expect Microcontrollers with separate but adjacent RAM might to have some restrictions. For example their may be no restrictions for the CPU, but the bus might prevent access to some blocks by DMA.

So, you might develop a program, then later discover it needs to use DMA. That would be a time when the behaviour might become 'unsafe'. Tracking down the bug might be hard if the memory needed in DMA transfers is crossing and uncrossing the memory boundary as the program evolves.

A second use of different segment names for the same memory is to 'reuse' memory at different stages in a programs lifecycle. For example some blocks of variables may be needed during an early phase of the program's lifetime, say for initialisation, but never later. So you could have the linker 'overlay' variables with disjoint lifetimes. This can be tricky to debug, and make maintenance significantly harder because your program is managing its variables lifetime.

What are you going to use the alternative memory segments (RAM0, RAM1, RAM0_M1PART1, and RAM1_PART2) for?

Are you planning to ask the linker to place variables or code in all four memory segments within one program? As explained above, that is unlikely to be safe unless you mange when the alternative memory segments are 'alive', so that their lifetimes don't overlap.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I realized that I described a wrong segments description for the second part. I won't have overlaps actually! But I think that I got the hardware explanations I was looking for. I will now try to find if this is possible with my MCU. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

For many kinds of memory access, the processor will have no reason to care about the boundaries between memory sections.  There are some times when it might matter, however.  On some TI DSPs, for example, there are regions of memory (called DARAM--Double Access RAM) that can--using a special instruction--simultaneously have read out a word and copy it over the preceding word.  Those instructions will fail if used on the first word of one of those memory regions, however, since there is no mechanism for selecting one region for the read and another for the write.  Unless one is using such mechanisms, however, most individual operations will take place entirely within a single memory region, and the processor won't care whether different operations in a sequence come from different places.

Comment: I am using a TI (C2000) so you are frightening me a bit ;)! Like you said, I now understand this is probably not a problem for the CPU but most likely it could be a memory controller limitation. Thanks :)!

Comment: @Plouff: For the TI C2000, the only time spanning memory regions is apt to be a problem would be with the instructions that include a data-move step (e.g. MACD).  Those can't cross memory-section boundaries.  Everything else will work fine across boundaries.

Comment: I'll have to check my assembly then... What kind of C code can produce instructions with data-move step? Thanks again!

Comment: @Plouff: It's possible to include such instructions within your program using "asm" directives, but the compiler won't generate them otherwise (the TI's instruction set is a bit goofy, but a dozen or so lines of well-placed assembly language may sometimes be able to speed up a hot loop by a factor of 10x or better).

Comment: I can assert that we don't include such instructions manually in the C code. We never had to optimize a bottleneck of the software so far. So we are "safe". Thanks a lot for all those hints!